# How to redirect cabal haddock output to a different folder?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

I have a test project with the following structure:

```
Test
  Test
    Test.hs
  Test.cabal
```

`Test.hs` is an empty module:

```
{-|
Description: Test

Test
-}
module Test.Test () where
```

`Test.cabal`:

```
cabal-version: 3.0
name: Test
version: 0.0.0
library
  build-depends: base
  exposed-modules: Test.Test
```

When I run `cabal haddock` it puts the docs in `dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-windows/ghc-8.10.1/Test-0.0.0/doc`.

Is there any way to redirect the output of `cabal haddock` to some other directory instead of burying it five layers deep in `dist-newstyle`?

Comment: I don't know how to configure the location of the HTML output. But note that (at least recent versions of) `cabal` support an `--open` flag that will open the generated haddocks in a browser: https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-project.html#cfg-flag---open

Comment: There's an `--htmldir` and `--docdir` option in cabal that seems relevant.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Neither flag changes the location of html files. (I tried ```cabal haddock --htmldir Docs``` and the same with ```-docdir```.)